# Python: If / Else Function, Iterative Maximization Problem

Tags: python, cvxpy

I have the following code which will only return "None" when the if/else piecewise function exceeds the given threshold. When run by itself (i.e. not with a range of values), it works okay but for some reason it fails to return values when above the if statement range. Can anyone assist?

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx
import scipy as sc
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
#Define Parameters
a = -1
b = 10**7
c = 0
alpha = 1/3
p = 0.004
q = 0.005
L = 10**6

#Define Objective Function
for w in range(10**5, 10**7, 100000):
    
    #Define Wealth Function
    def u(y):
        if w <= -((1-alpha)*b)/(2*a):
            return (a*y**2)+(b*y)+c
        else: 
            return (alpha*b*y)-((((1-alpha)**2)*(b**2))/(4*a))+c
    
    #Define Expected Utility
    def E(x):
        return p*u(w-L-(q*x)+x)+(1-p)*u(w-(q*x))
    
    x = cvx.Variable()
    obj = cvx.Minimize(-E(x))
    problem = cvx.Problem(obj)
    solution = problem.solve()
    
    print(w)
    print(x.value)
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. It can help to see how code works and where can be the mistake.

Comment: I'm not getting any kind of output when using the print() function.

Comment: you should use `print()` in different places to see which part of code is executed - and what you had in all variables in all moments.

Answer (score 0):

When your `else` in `u(y)` is hit (`w` around `3400000`), your problem has `solution == -inf` (check it with a print statement): there will be no x variable that solves it, hence the `None` in output.